# renaming files inside Sub directory with R

Tags: r, file, path, file-rename

I want to rename all jpeg files inside sub directory along with sub directory name with jpeg file for example

```
WorkingDirectory/FolderA/ -> a.jpg
WorkingDirectory/FolderB/ -> a.jpg
```

Want to change as

```
WorkingDirectory/FolderA/ -> FolderA-a.jpg
WorkingDirectory/FolderB/ -> FolderB-a.jpg
```

So far i'm using

```
old.names <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "jpeg$", recursive = TRUE)

new.names <- old.names
new.names  = gsub("/", "-", new.names)
new.names  = gsub(".jpeg", "", new.names)

final <- data.frame(do.call(cbind,mget(c('old.names','new.names'))))

final$old.names  = gsub("", "", final$old.names)
final$new.names  = gsub("", "", final$new.names)
file.rename(final$old.names, paste0(final$new.names, ".jpeg"))
```

I'm able to rename files but problem I'm facing with above code is that it moves all files into working directory as they should remain inside the sub directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're stripping the folder names from `new.names` in your sample code.

This should work:

```
old.names <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "jp[e]*g$", recursive = TRUE)
old.names;
#[1] "tmp/FolderA/a.jpg" "tmp/FolderB/b.jpg"

new.names <- sapply(strsplit(old.names, "/"), function(x)
    sprintf("%s/%s",
        paste0(x[1:(length(x) - 1)], collapse = "/"),
        paste0(x[(length(x) - 1):length(x)], collapse = "-")));
new.names;
#[1] "tmp/FolderA/FolderA-a.jpg" "tmp/FolderB/FolderB-b.jpg"

file.rename(old.names, new.names);
```

Explanation: Split `old.names` on `"/"`, then construct `new.names` by concatenating the first `n-1` entries with `"/"` (i.e. the folders), then adding the new filename which is generated by concatenating the last folder name and old filename with `"-"`.

Answer (score 2):

With your example above this seems sufficient:

```
old.names <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = "jpeg$", recursive = TRUE)

new.names <- old.names
new.names <- gsub("/", "-", new.names)
new.names <- file.path(dirname(old.names), new.names)

file.rename(old.names, new.names)
```

Comment: I believe this will produce `new.names` with `"WorkingDirectory/FolderA/WorkingDirectory-FolderA-a.jpg"`if executed from within `WorkingDirectory`, instead of `"WorkingDirectory/FolderA/FolderA-a.jpg"`.

Comment: `list.files` would list `FolderA/a.jpg` if `WorkingDirectory` is his working directory, which I was assuming

Comment: Yes, I agree, your solution works perfectly fine based on the assumption you give; however this will not work if you run the script outside of `"WorkingDirectory"`. TBH, it's not clear to me from which folder OP wants to rename files. That's why the solution I give should work for arbitrary subfolders.

Comment: yap "WorkingDirectory" was my working directory this one is much easier as well, it took me 4 hours to figure out importance of > dirname <